# create a dump of DOM using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, content-script

trying to figure out how to dump the complete dom into the local storage,i have found some methods but they involve manual tasks like copying the html code from the elements tab and dumping it into new file.I want to do this task using `content scipts`,as content scripts only have access to dom elements.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: the whole `DOM` not just the html...

Comment: complete webpage elements...including css

Comment: although my main goal is to find the difference between codes ....when the DOM changes due to node addtion or removal/attribute addition

Comment: Can you just use MutationObserver? Or do you want to compare to snapshots of the page taken at different moments in time (like today's versus yesterday's)?

Comment: yeah the latter one...

Comment: Well, if you don't need to save the internal element state (like the changed checkbox state or a different time in an audio/video player) then you can simply save HTML + CSS. Comparison of two snapshots will be nontrivial but maybe there are existing libraries just for that. If you'll have to implement it yourself, I guess you'd use DOMParser to construct DOM from HTML string and then recursively analyze/compare the snapshots.